# so torrc doesn't let me alter it

Tags: windows

i put HiddenServiceDirectory C:\Users\pedro\Documents\tor\hidden_service HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080 into torrc on the right spot but it just tells me tor unexpectedly quit.

if u know what to put on the torrc file for windows can u give me it in the answer so I can copy paste?